# How to config the 0x-api v4 environment variable ORDER_WATCHER_URL?

Tags: 0x

I'm tring to deploy 0x-api locally, when I use the api /sra/v4/order to create an order, I got the 500 Internal Server Error, the error log is :

```
[1644904993870] INFO  (26691 on DESKTOP-VKM9D90): request errored
    req: {
      "id": "cd210fa8-0ac4-4848-bb6b-b380f843fbbf",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/sra/v4/order",
      "query": {},
      "params": {},
      "headers": {
        "host": "172.28.210.112:6540",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-length": "801",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "origin": "http://localhost:3000",
        "referer": "http://localhost:3000/",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "accept-language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
      },
      "remoteAddress": "::ffff:172.28.208.1",
      "remotePort": 49295,
      "body": {
        "makerToken": "0x55D8C9bAe15019bFB02b52CB3ceEd05b783ea275",
        "takerToken": "0x3205e1c8832959c21207439bd33fc55279de98cc",
        "makerAmount": "100000000",
        "takerAmount": "100000000",
        "maker": "0x5409ed021d9299bf6814279a6a1411a7e866a631",
        "taker": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "chainId": 1337,
        "verifyingContract": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
        "takerTokenFeeAmount": "0",
        "sender": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "feeRecipient": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "pool": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "salt": "1644904988573",
        "expiry": "1644906189",
        "signature": {
          "r": "0x2cb96f8727562caa20913e99218a798858a26cbd11b528cf1de03403456fe1d5",
          "s": "0x1c9a2185df7740b040f8d6b27f490917b1ed5713ae18622b667558c7c8831603",
          "v": 27,
          "signatureType": 2
        }
      }
    }
    res: {
      "statusCode": 500,
      "headers": {
        "x-powered-by": "Express",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "content-length": "65",
        "etag": "W/\"41-4KPMPxCSTV9SE3PKzeD1vY+B2P8\""
      },
      "statusMessage": "Internal Server Error"
    }
    err: {
      "type": "Error",
      "message": "failed with status code 500",
      "stack":
          Error: failed with status code 500
              at ServerResponse.onResFinished (/home/cyrto/software/0x-api/node_modules/pino-http/logger.js:77:38)
              at ServerResponse.emit (node:events:532:35)
              at ServerResponse.emit (node:domain:475:12)
              at onFinish (node:_http_outgoing:830:10)
              at callback (node:internal/streams/writable:552:21)
              at afterWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:497:5)
              at afterWriteTick (node:internal/streams/writable:484:10)
              at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    }
    responseTime: 2013
```

I found the error was caused by send a timeout post http request, the source code is the following:

https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api/blob/master/src/utils/order_watcher.ts#L16

```
export class OrderWatcher implements OrderWatcherInterface {
    // tslint:disable:prefer-function-over-method
    public async postOrdersAsync(orders: SignedLimitOrder[]): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await axios.post(`${ORDER_WATCHER_URL}/orders`, orders, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                timeout: 1000,
            });
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.response.data) {
                throw new ValidationError(err.response.data.validationErrors);
            } else if (err.request) {
                throw new InternalServerError('failed to submit order to order-watcher');
            } else {
                throw new InternalServerError('failed to prepare the order-watcher request');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the source code has a Environment Variable named "ORDER_WATCHER_URL", so what should I do to config the variable?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is that you would need to run the `block-watcher`+ `order-watcher` yourselves. I’ve messaged you on Discord to discuss what’s needed to set this up.